# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am facing when trying to use local storage in my project. I have been trying to sign in and set the state for my both username and password. I am using two states instead of one and trying save the data in local storage using this approach.I have been attempting to sign in and set the state for my both username and password phrase. I'm utilizing two states rather than one and attempting save the information in neighborhood capacity utilizing this methodology.

Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Row, Col, Input, Button, Alert, Container, Label } from "reactstrap";

// Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// availity-reactstrap-validation
import { AvForm, AvField } from "availity-reactstrap-validation";

// actions
import { checkLogin, apiError } from "../../store/actions";
import { loginAction } from "../../redux/actions/authActions";

// import images
import logodark from "../../assets/images/logo-dark.png";
import logolight from "../../assets/images/logo-light.png";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "abc@gmail.com",
      password: "12345678",
      user: {},
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  async handleSubmit(event, values) {
    this.props.checkLogin(values, this.props.history);

    if (this.username && this.password) {
      // let action = await this.props.loginAction(
      //     {
      //     username: this.username,
      //     password: this.password,
      //     },
      //     () => {
      //     this.props.history.push({
      //         pathname: "/dashboard",
      //     });
      //     }
      // );

      let action = await this.props.loginAction(values, () => {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: "/dashboard",
        });
      });
    }
  }

  updateUser = (username, password) => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(username, password));
    this.setState({ username: username, password: password });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      // set username and password from local storage
      username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).username,
      password: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).password,
    });

    this.props.apiError("");
    document.body.classList.add("auth-body-bg");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("auth-body-bg");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <Container fluid className="p-0">
            <Row className="g-0">
              <Col lg={4}>
                <div className="authentication-page-content p-4 d-flex align-items-center min-vh-100">
                  <div className="w-100">
                    <Row className="justify-content-center">
                      <Col lg={9}>
                        <div>
                          <div className="text-center">
                            <div>
                              <Link to="/" class="">
                                <img
                                  src={logodark}
                                  alt=""
                                  height="20"
                                  class="auth-logo logo-dark mx-auto"
                                />
                                <img
                                  src={logolight}
                                  alt=""
                                  height="20"
                                  class="auth-logo logo-light mx-auto"
                                />
                              </Link>
                            </div>

                            <h4 className="font-size-18 mt-4">
                              Welcome Back !
                            </h4>
                            {/* <p className="text-muted">Sign in to continue to Nazox.</p> */}
                          </div>

                          {/* {this.props.loginError && this.props.loginError ? <Alert color="danger">{this.props.loginError}</Alert> : null} */}

                          <div className="p-2 mt-5">
                            <AvForm
                              className="form-horizontal"
                              onValidSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                            >
                              <div className="auth-form-group-custom mb-4">
                                <i className="ri-user-2-line auti-custom-input-icon"></i>
                                <Label htmlFor="username">Email</Label>
                                <AvField
                                  name="username"
                                  value={this.state.username}
                                  type="text"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  id="username"
                                  validate={{ email: true, required: true }}
                                  placeholder="Enter username"
                                />
                              </div>

                              <div className="auth-form-group-custom mb-4">
                                <i className="ri-lock-2-line auti-custom-input-icon"></i>
                                <Label htmlFor="userpassword">Password</Label>
                                <AvField
                                  name="password"
                                  value={this.state.password}
                                  type="password"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  id="userpassword"
                                  placeholder="Enter password"
                                />
                              </div>

                              {/* <div className="form-check">
                                                                <Input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="customControlInline" />
                                                                <Label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="customControlInline">Remember me</Label>
                                                            </div> */}

                              <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                                <Button
                                  color="primary"
                                  className="w-md waves-effect waves-light"
                                  type="submit"
                                >
                                  Log In
                                </Button>
                              </div>

                              {/* <div className="mt-4 text-center">
                                                                <Link to="/forgot-password" className="text-muted"><i className="mdi mdi-lock me-1"></i> Forgot your password?</Link>
                                                            </div> */}
                            </AvForm>
                          </div>

                          <div className="mt-5 text-center">
                            <p>
                              Don't have an account ?{" "}
                              <Link
                                to="/register"
                                className="fw-medium text-primary"
                              >
                                {" "}
                                Register{" "}
                              </Link>{" "}
                            </p>
                            {/* <p>© 2021 Nazox. Crafted with <i className="mdi mdi-heart text-danger"></i> by Themesdesign</p> */}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
              <Col lg={8}>
                <div className="authentication-bg">
                  <div className="bg-overlay"></div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  const { loginError } = state.Login;
  return { loginError };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStatetoProps, { checkLogin, apiError, loginAction })(Login)
);
```

[image]

Comment: I believe its because you are calling it in `componentDidMount`, which happens as soon as the DOM is inserted into the tree. It could very well be because initially you are trying to get data that is not there in LS. Does your localStorage already have the user object set?

Comment: no it doesnt set

Comment: Can you see in your browser dev tools how the object is being stored?

Comment: else, I believe you can try to store two entries, separatedly

localStorage.setItem("username", JSON.stringify(username))
localStorage.setItem("password", JSON.stringify(password))

and then call them

      username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("username")),
      password: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("password")),

Comment: If its not set, then you are trying to get data that doesn't exist. I believe you should ensure that you have the data before trying to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think currently you are storing 2 items in one string so for example:

```js
//  if you try to save such data
const username = 'admin'; 
const password = '123';
// below code will return this value: "'admin'"
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(username, password));
```

So, your **localStorage** value under key `'user'` is not an object, and you cannot access `.username` and `.password` keys. You can try to store **username** and **password** under separated keys or as one object:

> If you are not sure your data exists before saving in local storage you can try to save some weird message in LocalStorage (just for debugging) once you make sure you are saving your data correctly then you can get rid of this

```js
// Example 1
const username1 = null;
const password1 = '123';
localStorage.setItem('username', username1 ?? `DOESN'T EXISTS YET`);
localStorage.setItem('password', password1 ?? `DOESN'T EXISTS YET`);
console.log('USERNAME:', localStorage.getItem('username'));
console.log('PASSWORD:', localStorage.getItem('password'));

// Example 2
const username2 = 'admin';
const password2 = null;
localStorage.setItem('username-password', JSON.stringify({
  username: username2 ?? `DOESN'T EXISTS YET`,
  password: password2 ?? `DOESN'T EXISTS YET`
}));
console.log('USERNAME && PASSWORD', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username-password')));
```

If you are not familiar with `??` operator, you can check this link: *[Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)*

Comment: thanks Krzysztof Kaczyński